# Monitor SQL database changes

Tags: c#, sql

I have two applications, each with their own SQL DB's.  I have no control over the applications themselves, but I do have access to the databases.

What I'm looking to do is, when there is a change to the data for certain tables in App1, I need to either insert/update this data in the App2 database.  This needs to be done in a 'live' scenario and **not** by polling periodically.

Currently I have done this using triggers, but I would like to consider some alternatives.  I don't know if it is possible to create some sort of C# application which constantly runs in the background as a windows service or the like that monitors for changes.  The minimum SQL Server to support is 2005.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)?

Comment: IMO you're already doing it the right way. You could of course optionally build a proxy that those applications have to go through so you could monitor the statements but that's a little insane really.

Comment: Why were your triggers not suitable?

Comment: Thanks Simon.  Sorry I should have pointed out that the DB's aren't the same.  Don't they need to be for SQL Server Replication?  Also I need to do programmatic checks, for example when retrieving ID's for 'Codes' tables (Titles, Departments etc).  I'll update my original post.

Comment: @Adam not at all. There's a lot of room for manipulation/massaging of data in replication jobs.

Comment: @Mansfield, oh right great, I didn't realise that was possible.  This probably requires more investigation on my part.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, this site is amazing for response rate/time.  I'm used to waiting days+!

Comment: @Adam - As Mansfield mentioned replication can be done across varying DB's. I just completed a replication of AS400 data into a SQL Server system.

Comment: @SimonWilson - That's good to know, I'm going to look into replication a bit further.  Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SQLDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) for this if you really want to go the .NET route, but I can't imagine it being more efficient/better than simply using triggers as you've done already.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked into this and it looked like a viable solution.  

The issue I'm having at the moment, which may be down to my triggers, is that App1 updates it's database in a way that causes multiple triggers to be fired multiple times from one simple update in the front end.  Which in turn causes a delay on the front end.  (Also I trust my C# programming and error handling slightly more :))